# Firebase Dynamic Link with navigate cause infinity loop

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-dynamic-links

I created a firebase dynamic link from Firebase Console. I've tried implement it to my code and when I cold start my app by clicking the *example.page.link/ABCD* with navigate method it cause an infinity loop. If the app is in background it doesn't have any issue.

**Problem** :
The infinity loop trigger when the app from cold start with navigate to new page.

Any idea how to resolve this issue ?

> Edited

Example link : [www.example.com/testing?title=testing_deep_link](http://www.example.com/testing?title=testing_deep_link)

```
  Future firebaseDynamicLinkInit() async {
    final PendingDynamicLinkData data =
        await FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.getInitialLink();
    _handleDeepLink(data);

    FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.onLink(
        onSuccess: (PendingDynamicLinkData dynamicLinkData) async {
      _handleDeepLink(dynamicLinkData);
    }, onError: (OnLinkErrorException e) async {
      print('${e.message}');
    });
  }
```

```
  void _handleDeepLink(PendingDynamicLinkData data) {
    final Uri deepLink = data?.link;
    if (deepLink != null) {
      var title = deepLink.queryParameters['title'];

      if (title != null) {
        // START This part trigger the problem
        Navigator.of(context).popUntil((route) => route.isFirst);
        Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/Pages', arguments: 6);
        // END This part trigger the problem
      }
    }

    return null;
  }
```

Comment: Can you share some part of the code.

Comment: @AjayKumar I've edited the post with code. You can have a look now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**THREAD CLOSED**

I apologize for my carelessness.

I found the mistake i'd made. I shouldn't use navigate push because this route '/Pages' will recreate the page and run the *firebaseDynamicLinkInit()* again and again (infinity loop).

The route '/Pages' *initState()* include *firebaseDynamicLinkInit()* causes infinity loop.

```
 // START This part trigger the problem
 Navigator.of(context).popUntil((route) => route.isFirst);
 Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/Pages', arguments: 6);
 // END This part trigger the problem
```

Comment: Not sure if this is the right approach. The `getInitialLink()` documentation says it returns null after the first attempt.